# Path substitution with sed and shell variables on OS X

Tags: shell, sed, string-interpolation

I am on Mac OS X and using sed for an in-place replacement.

Essentially I have this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
PREFIX="$1"

sed -i bak -e 's|OCAMLDIR|"${PREFIX}"|g' ocamloptrev
```

Where `PREFIX` is a path, hence I'm using the `|`.

Unfortunately, the variable in the file path is not getting evaluated as I expected, I end up with:

```
OCAMLC="${PREFIX}"/bin/ocamlopt
```

How can I get the right evaluation of `${PREFIX}` into the `sed` command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
PREFIX="$1"

sed -i bak -e 's|OCAMLDIR|'"${PREFIX}"'|g' ocamloptrev
```

What you're basically doing, is "exiting"/getting outside the single-quoted string, entering into a double-quoted string, interpreting the variable inside double-quotes, and then entering the single quotes again.

With this simple example, we could also just use double-quotes, which allow variables to be interpreted:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
PREFIX="$1"

sed -i bak -e "s|OCAMLDIR|${PREFIX}|g" ocamloptrev
```

If you try to use double-quotes (`""`) inside single-quotes, they don't get interpreted either. [This part of the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) explains this in more detail.

> **3.1.2.2 Single Quotes**
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘`'`’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> **3.1.2.3 Double Quotes**
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘`"`’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`. The characters `$` and `` ` `` retain their special meaning within double quotes (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions)).  ...

Comment: The first code would run into problems if `${PREFIX}` contained spaces etc.  You should enclose that in double quotes: `'s|OCAMLDIR|'"${PREFIX}"'|g'` to be safe.  Otherwise, your answer is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Shell variables are not expanded inside single quotes (there are no metacharacters within single quotes, not even backslashes), so you need to use something like this, with the double quotes around `${PREFIX}` ensuring that spaces etc in the value are handled correctly:

```
sed -i bak -e 's|OCAMLDIR|'"${PREFIX}"'|g' ocamloptrev
```

Or you could even use:

```
sed -i bak -e "s|OCAMLDIR|${PREFIX}|g" ocamloptrev
```

The latter is safe because the material inside the double quotes does not contain shell metacharacters (dollar signs, backslashes and back-quotes are the main danger signs).  If there were dodgy characters in the rest of the string, the first version is safer to use.

Personally, I'd use `.bak` rather than just `bak` as the suffix.